# How to Draw Path between start location and end location with multiple waypoints on google map in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to  Draw Path between start location and end location with multiple waypoints on google map in android along with i want to give numbering to the point for example start point is 1 and onward Please help.

Comment: Hi Chetak, did you ever get a solution to this?  I am developing an app that requires similar functionality - I can get the start point and end point to work, but I would like to add waypoints as well.  Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.addAll(<routePoints must be List<LatLng> points>);
polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
polylineOptions.width(10);
polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am sending request to google with start,destination and waypoints with optimized=true i am getting route but i want optimized points to plot on map

Comment: I have that code but unable to post that here in stack overflow that too big involving model classes and decoder classes to read google response, if you are able to decode polyline object then you can use polyline to draw route

Comment: @MohdMufiz Hi Mohd, do you have any of this code in github?  I can tap 2 points on a map and get the directions between them, but I would like to add waypoints by tapping on more points.  Can you post some of the code to do this?  Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Kevin I don't have code but you can try this solution

Add your tap points in the arraylist and draw the line from (n-1)th point to n point, in this way when u tap first time (n-1)==0 so ignore this, then on second tap (n-1)==0 and n=1 so draw line to 0 to 1, then on third tap (n-1)==1 and n==2, so draw line on that and so on